# When calling createNewFile() in android/java, why do I get: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, file

We have tried to create a file in android by getting a path, making a new directory and then creating a file in that directory, but we get an error on runtime.
Here is the code:

```java
private File createTestFile() throws IOException {
    String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/RNDAlexaData/";
    Log.d("rootpath", rootPath);
    File root = new File(rootPath);
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    File f = new File(rootPath + "test.pcm");
    if (f.exists()) {
        f.delete();
    }
    f.createNewFile();
  
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);

    out.flush();
    out.close();

    return f;
}
```

Output from android:

```java
D/rootpath: /storage/emulated/0/RNDAlexaData/
D/Response error: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at aut.rnd.alexa.ui.account.AccountFragment$TokenListener.createTestFile(AccountFragment.java:318)
```

Android Manifest has these permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Use `File f = new File(rootPath, "test.pcm");` or `File f = new File(root, "test.pcm");` instead of string concatenation. Don't know if it'll make a difference, but it's the right may to do it.

Comment: For the same reason, you should also use `File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "RNDAlexaData");`

Comment: `root.mkdirs();` If you had checked the return value you would have found out that the directory is not created. You should have displayed a toast there to inform the user. And then you should have returned as it does not make sense trying to create a file in an directory that does not exist.

Comment: @Andreas you ment: For the same reason, you should also use File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "RNDAlexaData");

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky bro, this was a year ago lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my own problem with the help of googling and @blackapps & @Andreas in the comments.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` was deprecated, use `mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()` instead.

```
private File createTestFile() throws IOException {
    File dataFolder = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "RNDAlexaData");
    Log.d("parent", dataFolder.getParent());

    if (!dataFolder.exists()) {
        Log.d("mkdir_success", "Succesfully created directory: " + dataFolder.mkdirs());
    }
    else {
        Log.d("fileexists", "true");
    }

    File testMediaFile = new File(dataFolder, "test.pcm");
    if (testMediaFile.exists()) {
        testMediaFile.delete();
    }
    Log.d("media_file", "successfully created: " + testMediaFile.createNewFile());

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(testMediaFile);
    // TODO
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    return testMediaFile;
}
```